# Error in prepare Statement in Postgres stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

While creating the stored procedure in Postgres, I am getting an error at the prepare statement.

This is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE public.deletebyidref(IN idref character varying, IN tablename character varying)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
   elapsed timestamp;
   t varchar(50);
   q varchar(50);
   w varchar(50);
   count int;
BEGIN

    elapsed := now(6);

    t := replace(tableName, ';', '&#059;');
    w := replace(idRef, ';', '&#059;');
    q := concat('delete from ', tableName, ' where idRef=''', w, '''');

    prepare stmt FROM q;
    execute q;
    count := row_count();
    deallocate prepare stmt;
    elapsed := timediff(now(6), elapsed);

END ;
$$;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why a `prepare` at all? You could simplify that using `execute format('delete from ... where idref=$1') using w`. There is also no `timediff()` function in Postgres. And `now()` won't change during the function as it shows the time at the start of the transactions, you need to use `clock_timestamp()`

Comment: “An error”, but the error is classified information?

Answer (score 0):

You should not to use `PREPARE` statement in PL/pgSQL. This is MySQL way how to run dynamic SQL. But in Postgres in PL/pgSQL just run `EXECUTE` command.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN